# Use github clone to develop my own

Tags: angularjs, github, ionic-framework

i am very new to github. Is it possible to have a whole code from github and edit at our own to make the other product such different design and additional functionality. The link is the thing i refer to. https://github.com/zoomix/ionic_feeder

Comment: you mean like fork it?

Comment: yes. I want the entire file to kickstart my project and able to run using ionic serve

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Ionic Feeder is licensed under the terms of the GPL license. That means you can fork the code in GitHub and change it, as long as you adhere to the terms of the GPL license.

For example, if you redistribute your modified app, you need to give your end users access to the source code of your modified app.

You can find the license file for that repository here: https://github.com/zoomix/ionic_feeder/blob/master/LICENSE

Answer (score 0):

Refer this manual for installing git in your system.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

After you have installed enter the following command to clone

```
git clone https://github.com/zoomix/ionic_feeder
```

This will clone the folder in your system.  You will have a folder names "ionic_feeder-master". cd into that folder and start working.

I suggest you read the following link for understanding. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: hi sridharan. So i have clone the repository. How can i run the file

Comment: I clearly don't want the project is about. As I see www folder and html pages, I hope it is a web application. (If that is case you can follow this.) If you have installed wamp or xampp then put it in correct folder (www in case of wamp) and run it in localhost! Also consider Frederik Carlier's answer regarding license. Under GPL license you cannot claim proprietorship i.e., code has to be made open source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer